# Recursion Function to count the occurrence of a digit in a number (python)

Tags: python, function, recursion, counting

I need to find out the amount of times that the number one is in a number.
Here is what I have:

Sample input: 11001

Desired output: 3

```
def oneCount(n):
    n = str(n)
    if n == '1':
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + oneCount(n[:-1])

print oneCount(1100)
```

Right now it returns the amount of digits but not the amount of ones.

Comment: Can you show a sample input and desire out put ? and whats `Fiver` ?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment that requires a recursive function?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It is recursion practice - i am trying to familiarize myself with recursion functions

Comment: Only add one to the return if the last digit is actually 1. You're not checking that in the second return. ``return (n[-1] == '1') + oneCount(n[:-1])``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def oneCount(n):    
    n = str(n)
    # Here, you check if the entire string is '1'.
    # Not sure if you mean to check if a single digit is '1'.
    if n == '1':
        return 1
    else:
        # If the entire string is not '1', you recur on all but the least significant digit.
        return 1 + oneCount(n[:-1])
print oneCount(1100)
```

Walk:

```
oneCount(1100) -> '1100' is not '1'. recurs on 1 + oneCount('110')
1 + oneCount('100') -> '110' is not '1'. recurs on 1 + (1 + oneCount('11'))
2 + oneCount('00') -> '11' is not '1'. recurs on 2 + (1 + oneCount('1'))
3 + oneCount('0') -> '1' is '1'. return 1
4
```

OK, so that's a wrong answer, but perhaps more insidious, what if your most significant digit weren't 1?

```
oneCount(2)
>>> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

You end up recurring on the empty string. The empty string isn't '1', so the recursion is infinite!

When recurring over an iterable like a string or a list, a good rule of thumb is to consider the empty iterable your base case.

```
def oneCount(i):
    i = str(i)
    if i == '':
        return 0
    # Do not recur in the base case, above
    # The below cases are not the base case, so expect to recur
    # What is the nature of the recursion?
    car, cdr = i[0], i[1:] # silly lisp reference
    if car == '1':
        ???
    # else?
```

### Just for fun

#### Booleans as integers

Consider that a boolean value is equivalent to an integer value of 1 or 0 in Python. You can add that value to an integer.

> return (car == 1) + oneCount(cdr)

#### Radical

Consider that you don't need to convert an integer into a string in order to iterate over it. Consider `cdr, car = divmod(i, 10)`, or more plainly, `cdr, car = i // 10, i % 10`. What's fun is that gives you the ability to count the occurrence of digits in a number in any base.

```
def oneCount(i, base=10):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    cdr, car = divmod(i, base)
    if car == 1:
        ???
    ???

>>> oneCount(int('111111100000', 2), 2)
7
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
def oneCount(n):
    n = str(n)
    # if we have reached the end of n return 0
    if not n:
        return 0
    # check current n[0] is == 1 and move right one char in n
    else:
        return (n[0] == "1") + oneCount(n[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to answer this in the first place, but all the bad answers kind of force me to...

First of all, a recursion as a terminal case and a recursive case. The terminal case is the case where you can immediately tell the result. For your task, it is the empty string, because it contains zero ones:

```
if n == '':
  return 0
```

In the recursive case, you have to check wheter your string starts with a 1 or not:

```
if n.startswith('1'):
  return 1+oneCount(n[1:])
else:
  return oneCount(n[1:])
```

Also, you are converting `n` to a string every time, which is not neccessary.

A pythonic solution would use `if not n:` instead of `if n == '':`, so a complete solution could look like

```
def oneCountRecur(n):
  if not n:
    return 0

  if n.startswith('1'):
    return 1 + oneCountRecur(n[1:])
  else:
    return oneCountRecur(n[1:])

def oneCount(n):
  return oneCountRecur(str(n))
```

The `else:` above `return oneCountRecur(n[1:])` can be left out, it's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: The `else` isn't optional, without it you don't always return.

Comment: Why would the last else statement be optional? The function will then return `None` if n does not start with 1. And give a exception since you can't add None to a integer

Comment: I mean only the `else` is optional.

Comment: You could even drop the `if` statement and just do `return n.startswith('1') + oneCountRecur(n[1:])`

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to be as readable as possible because of OPs obvious difficulties to understand recursion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you insists on a recursive solution. Here we go

```
def oneCount(n):
    digits = str(n)
    count = 1 if digits.startswith('1') else 0
    for digit in digits[1:]:  # start looping from next digit
        count += oneCount(digit)
    return count
```

EDIT: In case you dont consider the above function as recursive enough:

```
def oneCount(n):
    digits = str(n)
    count = 1 if digits.startswith('1') else 0
    if len(digits) > 1: 
        count += oneCount(digits[1:])
    return count
```

Comment: This is not recursive. There are already two good answers, why post a bad one?

Comment: When a function calls its self, that is recursion. Explain to me why do you say it is not recursive.

Comment: Well, it is *somewhat* recursive, but the recursion depth will never exceed 2, because you *iterate* over the string's suffix and call oneCount with strings of length 1, so no more recursion occurs.

Comment: But you said it is not recursive. So you have to pass the whole chunk of the list to be convinced its recursive?

Comment: Yes. If you do recursive programming tasks, iterative loops are usually forbidden. And why would someone use the first suggestion? If I can use `for`, I'd clearly use `for digit in digits: ...`.

Comment: But `for digit in digits:` won't work since you are not chopping the original list down. You will hit an infinite loop. Both those suggestions are equivalent. First one chops the list down and passes 1 character to the function recursively. The second one chops the list down and send the sublist as an argument to the function recursively. By list/sublist i mean string/subsring in this context.

Comment: Sorry for omitting the body. I'd do `count=0; for digit in digits: if digit =='1': count+=1`. Why should one mix recursive and iterative approach?

Comment: Besides pedagogical instruction, I dont understand why should you not.

Answer (score 0):

```
def oneCount(n):  
    if not n:  
        return 0  
    else:  
        return (n % 10 == 1) + oneCount(n // 10)
```